# Error: There is already an option for the mobileEmulation capability. Please use that instead. Parameter name: capabilityName

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've updated Selenium Webdriver C# to the version 2.50.0 and unfortunately I also updated `ChromeDriver` to the version 2.21 and then I've encountered a problem. I'm inclined to think it's connected with the new version of `ChromeDriver` but I'm also not sure about new version of Selenium.

**I used the next piece of code to run mobile emulation:**

```
var mobileEmulation = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
     {"deviceName", device}
};

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
```

And this worked well.

**Now on the next string:**

```
options.AddAdditionalCapability("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
```

**It shown me the next error:**

> There is already an option for the mobileEmulation capability. Please
>   use that instead. Parameter name: `capabilityName`

So what should I use as the first parameter in this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct thing to do here is to use the `EnableMobileEmulation` method on the `ChromeOptions` object. There are two overloads. The first overload takes a string, which is intended to be used with a device name. The second overload takes a `ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings` object, on which you set things like height, width, and pixel ratio. This method allows the use of type-safe parameters, and which allows you to set the `mobileEmulation` capability correctly. The code would look something like this:

```
// Assumes deviceName is a string variable containing the name
// of the device to emulate.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.EnableMobileEmulation(deviceName);
```

Note: This answer refers to the 2.50.1 release of the .NET bindings, which corrects the API in this area.

Comment: Thanks a lot! When will this version be uploaded to the public use?

Comment: @DenisKoreyba It was made publicly available earlier today (28 January 2016.

Answer (score 2):

That check was added less than a day ago in Selenium 2.50:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/6db8a5fd2bf8a1fc89d41467d1f21d073ffadfe0

I haven't found any documentation, but it seems you need to use the new type-safe `ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings` class to set mobile emulation options. Hopefully it's clear enough from the above diff what you need to change.